# Low-light photography: How much light reflects off a surface

Tags: digital, sensor, low-light, light, physics

I'm looking at light levels for photography and I'm trying to figure out how much light hits my sensor. There are [plenty of tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux#Illuminance) online which give light levels, but that's only directly relevant if I'm photographing the light sources themselves. Since I'm photographing objects instead, I only get the reflected light. How much reflection can I expect?

Obviously this will depend on many particulars -- if I was shooting a mirror reflecting the light source it would be nearly 100%, while an all-black scene or distant objects might be almost 0%. But I'd like to get an idea of what's typical, or even better a range of examples.

I assume that distance works normally, with light levels falling off as the inverse square pf distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various sources indicate that *average* reflectance of surfaces is somewhere between 12-18%.

Calculating exposure from table values is not very typical. Most photographers would use a light meter, either built in or external.

Comment: Thank you -- I appreciate that this is not a typical question. :)